# Can I get the timestamp for a transaction added to mempool?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, ether, etherscan, blocks

Can I get the time stamp on when a transaction was added to the mempool and when it was successfully added to a block?

Is there an API to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get a timestamp for the transaction when it was added to the mempool because transactions do not have a concept of time, only `blockNumber`. While in the mempool, the transaction's `blockNumber` parameter is `None`.

Once a miner has included a transaction into a block, the transaction will update with the appropriate `blockNumber` that it was included in. That block also has a timestamp associated with it, so you can now get a time that the transaction was included in the blockchain.